# How do I fix a button to bottom screen in NativeScript

Tags: css, nativescript

I have a multi-page form and I would like the continue button to be fixed in one spot throughout the form.

Below is a pic that shows what I am trying to do.

On the pages that are short, I still want the button on bottom. Same with long pages, still want it there.

Can anyone help me with a prototype?

Thank you.

John
 [image: UI]

Comment: You could simply use a StackLayout to stack items one after another. If you want to keep the button always dock at bottom of screen then use a GridLayout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use flexbox to do that.

```css
main {
  height: 400px;
  background-color: limegreen;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.actions {
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="content">
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    
    <p>Here some content</p>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <button>Submit</button>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: That worked! Now, I need to dig into FlexBox and learn how to use it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The above one works fine, you can also achieve the same user interface with grid layout.
if you know the height of bottom view.

```
<GridLayout rows="*,40" class="home-panel">
    <Image row="0"  src="{{ url_1 }}" />
    <Image row="1"  src="{{ url_2 }}" />
 </GridLayout>
```